# How to share a folder in dropbox without placing it in the dropbox folder?

Tags: windows, share, dropbox

I'm trying to share a folder in my machine that is not inside the dropbox folder.
On my Mac i did that using symbolic links:

```
cd ˜/Dropbox
ln -s {folder i want to share} {link name}
```

It really works very well, but I'm trying to do the same on a Windows PC.
Does anyone know how to do that?
Just creating a plain shortcut does not work.

I also tried to create a symbolic link using "mklink /D" and it did not work either. :-(

Also tried Sysinternals Junction and no success.

Thanks,

Ecil

PS: Junction creates a folder inside Dropbox folder with the same contents as the linked folder and synchronizes to other devices, but as soon as I make an update to any of the files in the linked folder (or add a new one) it does not reflect these changes to other devices/computers.